# Вывод форм-рисунков в одной "строке", без тега <table>

Tags: html, css, html5, form

Кусок кода:

```
<form action="/exeuser.php" method="post">
                <input type="image" src="stopfr.gif" alt="stopfr">
                <input type="hidden" name="exe" value="stopfr">
                <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="
                <?php
                echo $uid;
                ?>
                       ">
            </form>

            <form action="/exeuser.php" method="post">
                   <input type="image" src="sendmes.png" alt="sendpm">
                <input type="hidden" name="exe" value="sendpm">
                <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="
                <?php
                echo $uid;
                ?>

                       " />
               </form>
```

Выводит формы-рисунки сверху вниз. скрин http://itmages.ru/image/view/4359322/ee1e7de1

Если каждую рисунок-форму  размещать в ячейке таблицы, то все хорошо отображается http://itmages.ru/image/view/4359325/94bf9648

Если рисунки-формы размещать в одной ячейке, то показываются они вертикально (не так как нужно).
Как сделать так, чтобы рисунки были в "одной строке" (то есть выводились так как в примере во по второй ссылке)? Нужно (желательно) это сделать без таблицы.

---

Я не знаю как вставить изображение в вопрос, поэтому указал ссылки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропиши у картинок `display:inline-block;` в стилях

UPD:

```html
<form action="/exeuser.php" method="post" style="display:inline-block;">
  <input type="image" src="https://yastatic.net/web4/_/JsViUZKr8YfX2xwqJy4tLvde-tE.svg" alt="stopfr">
  <input type="hidden" name="exe" value="stopfr">
  <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="
                <?php
                echo $uid;
                ?>
                       ">
</form>

<form action="/exeuser.php" method="post" style="display:inline-block;">
  <input type="image" src="https://yastatic.net/web4/_/JsViUZKr8YfX2xwqJy4tLvde-tE.svg" alt="sendpm">
  <input type="hidden" name="exe" value="sendpm">
  <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="
                <?php
                echo $uid;
                ?>

                       " />
</form>
```

Comment: а без стиля к какому именно тегу лепить display:inline-block?

Comment: напишите подробнее, на основе примера выше указанного кода, где именно нужно это написать.

Comment: Дописал в inline стилях, но правильней вынести все в css файл.

Comment: ну вот совсем другое дело. +

Comment: аааааааа, а вы уверены что именно ДЛЯ КАРТИНОК, а не для форм нужно прописать .... ааа ну впринцмпе я понял. вы имели в виду под словом "картинка" ФОРМУ. Тогда я понял почему у меня вчера ничего не получалось. Я не мог понять куда и как вписать display:inline-block;. Но уже все понял - записал в css. С другими формами буду внимательней. или запишу в сss #onerow - ну что-то придумаю.

Answer (score -1):

```
form input:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

или

```
input { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: :(( не знаю. у меня не получается. наверное придется с таблицами работать.